# Before IOS5 I could cause a PDF within a UIWebView to scroll using Javascript. How do I do this under IOS5?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, ios5

On previous versions of IOS the following code works

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
int height = ([self.page intValue] - 1) * pageHeight;
    if (isProCards)
        height = ([self.page intValue] - 1) * proPageHeight;
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0, %d);", height];
[self.web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
}
```

It no longer works on IOS5. Does anyone know any other way of getting a webview to scroll when displaying a PDF?

Thanks,

Joe

P.S. I have confirmed that javascript still runs, its just that scrolling doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIScrollView` is exposed in IOS5, this means that you can do this:

`[web.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offset)];`

The only caveat is that this can't be called from the `webViewDidFinishLoad` method. You have to use an `NSTimer` to execute the code after the web view has loaded and is scrollable.

Joe